# How to avoid Spring's @RequestMapping paths conflicts?

Tags: java, spring, rest, path, conflict

I'd like to define REST API using Spring. I have these 2 @Controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{machineId}/workspaces/{workspaceId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void removeWorkspace(@PathVariable String machineId, @PathVariable String workspaceId {...}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{machineId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void removeVM(@PathVariable String machineId) {...}
```

The problem is, that this definition causing path conflicts: if I attempt to call

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost/machine-1/workspaces/workspace-1
```

I would expect, that the "removeWorkspace" should be called, but the problem is, that the "removeVM" is called. Does anybody get idea how to avoid such conflict? {machineId} prefix probably cause this conflict. Of course I'd like to keep those paths unchanged.

Thanks

Comment: Show, please, the exception on the matter.

Comment: Which exception? There is no exception, just Spring calls wrong method.

Comment: OK. `Best match`. Investigating...

Comment: Just tested it with Spring MVC 4.0.3 and it works well

Comment: Thanks for testing. I'm on Spring 3.1.1

Comment: Seems for there was an issue on the matter which has been fixed. Sorry, can't find it.

Comment: try updating second @RequestMapping(value = "/{machineId}" to @RequestMapping(value = "/{machineId}*" and please tell me the result :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC RequestMapping matches wrong URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992637/spring-mvc-requestmapping-matches-wrong-url)

Comment: My question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992637/spring-mvc-requestmapping-matches-wrong-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug fixed meanwhile fixed in version 4.1-RC2, see this JIRA [SPR-10576](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10576) for further details.

So it seems the only way to fix it in your current version would be to change the URL paths, or to apply the patch manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a regular expression to explain spring that `@RequestMapping(value = "/{machineId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)` should not match `http://localhost/machine-1/workspaces/workspace-1`

I have not tryed this before, but maybe it works for you:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{machineId:[^/]*}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
  public void removeVM(@PathVariable String machineId) {...}
```